# How to put two svg animations in one column?

Tags: php, jquery, svg

I'm new in SVG animations, i want to put `svg animations` on my website. I created two SVG animations using `lazy line painter` composer, but I can’t connect two animations at once, only one of them works. If taken separately, both animations work perfectly.

JS connect of animations:

```
<script>
     (function(){ 
      document.onreadystatechange = () => {
               if (document.readyState === 'complete') {                            
                    /**
                     * Setup your Lazy Line element.
                     * see README file for more settings
                     */    
                    let el = document.querySelector('#teamwork');
                    let myAnimation = new LazyLinePainter(el, {"ease":"easeLinear","strokeWidth":5.1,"strokeOpacity":1,"strokeColor":"black","strokeCap":"square","delay":1360}); 
                    myAnimation.paint(); 
                  }
                }

              })();

            </script>
            <script>
              (function(){ 
                document.onreadystatechange = () => {

                  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {           
                   /**
                     * Setup your Lazy Line element.
                     * see README file for more settings
                     */

                    let el = document.querySelector('#employee');
                    let myAnimation = new LazyLinePainter(el, {"ease":"easeLinear","strokeWidth":8.6,"strokeOpacity":0.8,"strokeColor":"#222F3D","delay":280}); 
                    myAnimation.paint(); 
                  }
                }
              })();
            </script>
```

First animation:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="teamwork" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 312.009 312.009" style="enable-background:new 0 0 312.009 512.009;" xml:space="preserve" data-llp-composed="true" class="lazy-line-painter">
<g>
  <g>
    <circle cx="255.999" cy="64.005" r="64" data-llp-id="teamwork-0" data-llp-duration="1030" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
  </g>
</g>
<g>
  <g>
    <path d="M351.871,301.957l-14.528-113.152c-1.632-16.416-15.328-28.8-31.808-28.8h-17.536c-4.256,0-8.32,1.696-11.328,4.672&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;l-20.672,20.672l-20.672-20.672c-3.008-2.976-7.072-4.672-11.328-4.672h-17.504c-16.512,0-30.208,12.384-31.808,28.384&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;l-14.56,113.6c-0.576,4.544,0.832,9.152,3.872,12.576c3.04,3.456,7.392,5.44,12,5.44h17.28l13.376,163.2&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;c1.6,16.384,15.328,28.8,31.84,28.8h35.04c16.512,0,30.208-12.416,31.872-29.088l13.344-162.912h17.248&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;c4.608,0,8.96-1.984,12-5.44C351.071,311.141,352.479,306.533,351.871,301.957z" data-llp-id="teamwork-1" data-llp-duration="1030" data-llp-delay="1030" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
  </g>
</g>
<g>
  <g>
    <circle cx="415.999" cy="64.005" r="64" data-llp-id="teamwork-2" data-llp-duration="1030" data-llp-delay="2060" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
  </g>
</g>
<g>
  <g>
    <path d="M95.999,0.005c-35.296,0-64,28.704-64,64s28.704,64,64,64c35.264,0,64-28.704,64-64S131.263,0.005,95.999,0.005z" data-llp-id="teamwork-3" data-llp-duration="1030" data-llp-delay="3090" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
  </g>
</g>
<g>
  <g>
    <path d="M511.871,301.957l-14.528-113.12c-1.632-16.448-15.296-28.832-31.808-28.832h-17.536c-4.256,0-8.32,1.696-11.328,4.672&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;l-20.672,20.672l-20.672-20.672c-3.008-2.976-7.072-4.672-11.296-4.672h-17.536c-1.984,0-3.776,0.704-5.664,1.056&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;c4.128,7.296,7.36,15.2,8.32,24.064l14.496,112.768c1.792,13.728-2.496,27.552-11.712,37.952&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;c-4.352,4.992-9.92,8.512-15.872,11.264l10.624,104.096c1.632,16.416,15.328,28.8,31.84,28.8h35.04&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;c16.512,0,30.208-12.416,31.872-29.088l13.312-130.912h17.248c4.608,0,8.96-1.984,12-5.44&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;C511.071,311.141,512.479,306.533,511.871,301.957z" data-llp-id="teamwork-4" data-llp-duration="1030" data-llp-delay="4120" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
  </g>
</g>
<g>
  <g>
    <path d="M139.967,335.685c-9.088-10.272-13.312-24.064-11.584-37.728l14.56-113.632c0.832-8.512,3.968-16.192,7.968-23.296&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;c-1.792-0.32-3.488-1.024-5.376-1.024h-17.536c-4.256,0-8.32,1.696-11.328,4.672l-20.672,20.672l-20.672-20.672&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;c-3.008-2.976-7.072-4.672-11.296-4.672H46.494c-16.512,0-30.208,12.384-31.808,28.384l-14.56,113.6&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;c-0.576,4.544,0.832,9.152,3.872,12.576c3.04,3.456,7.424,5.44,12,5.44h17.28l13.376,131.2c1.6,16.384,15.328,28.8,31.84,28.8&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;h35.04c16.512,0,30.208-12.416,31.872-29.088l10.624-103.84C150.047,344.293,144.447,340.741,139.967,335.685z" data-llp-id="teamwork-5" data-llp-duration="1030" data-llp-delay="5150" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
  </g>
</g>

</svg>
```

Second animation:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="employee" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 511.999 511.999" style="enable-background:new 0 0 511.999 511.999;" xml:space="preserve" width="512px" height="512px" class="lazy-line-painter" data-llp-composed="true"><g transform="matrix(0.960596 0 0 0.960596 10.0874 10.0874)"><g>
  <g>
    <path d="M458.841,340.284h-12.533v-97.791c0-1.644-0.54-3.241-1.537-4.548l-36.051-47.269c3.506-4.608,5.592-10.351,5.592-16.574    c0-15.124-12.305-27.429-27.429-27.429c-15.124,0-27.429,12.305-27.429,27.429c0,15.125,12.305,27.429,27.429,27.429    c3.47,0,6.789-0.655,9.849-1.836l34.574,45.333v95.257h-35.85v-21.744c0-4.142-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5s-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5v21.744    h-32.537v-58.72c0-4.142-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5c-4.142,0-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5v58.72h-45.405l-12.952-76.52l3.642-5.481    c3.224,2.29,6.419,3.915,11.108,2.742c3.406-0.852,6.259-3.143,7.827-6.285l18.297-36.67l41.782,16.181    c1.139,0.492,23.239,10.412,23.239,36.369v12.918c0,4.142,3.358,7.5,7.5,7.5s7.5-3.358,7.5-7.5v-12.918    c0-36.448-31.25-49.714-32.58-50.261c-0.047-0.02-0.095-0.039-0.143-0.057l-70.727-27.391v-15.053    c11.085-8.849,18.857-21.68,21.1-36.316c5.524-0.627,10.649-2.804,14.887-6.449c5.951-5.118,9.365-12.564,9.365-20.429    c0-6.335-2.216-12.397-6.186-17.189V75.818C331.173,34.012,297.16,0,255.355,0s-75.818,34.012-75.818,75.818V98.04    c-4.012,4.735-6.183,10.508-6.183,16.621c0,7.866,3.413,15.314,9.365,20.432c4.249,3.654,9.39,5.834,14.933,6.453    c2.27,14.272,10.001,27.982,22.26,37.238v14.127l-70.65,27.39c-0.047,0.018-0.094,0.037-0.141,0.056    c-1.331,0.547-32.58,13.814-32.58,50.261v69.664H80.691v-95.257l34.574-45.333c3.059,1.181,6.378,1.836,9.849,1.836    c15.125,0,27.429-12.305,27.429-27.429s-12.305-27.429-27.429-27.429s-27.429,12.305-27.429,27.429    c0,6.223,2.087,11.967,5.592,16.574l-36.051,47.269c-0.997,1.307-1.537,2.905-1.537,4.548v97.791H53.158    c-9.147,0-16.587,7.44-16.587,16.587v38.885c0,9.14,7.429,16.574,16.566,16.586v84.039c0,8.613,7.006,15.619,15.619,15.619    h169.743c4.142,0,7.5-3.358,7.5-7.5s-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5H68.755c-0.341,0-0.618-0.277-0.618-0.618v-84.038h375.725v84.038    c0,0.341-0.277,0.618-0.618,0.618H273.5c-4.142,0-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5s3.358,7.5,7.5,7.5h169.743    c8.613,0,15.619-7.006,15.619-15.619v-84.039c9.137-0.012,16.566-7.447,16.566-16.586V356.87    C475.428,347.724,467.988,340.284,458.841,340.284z M386.885,186.528c-6.852,0-12.428-5.575-12.428-12.428    s5.575-12.428,12.428-12.428c6.853,0,12.428,5.575,12.428,12.428C399.313,181.035,393.592,186.528,386.885,186.528z     M125.114,161.673c6.853,0,12.428,5.575,12.428,12.428c0,6.853-5.575,12.428-12.428,12.428c-6.707,0-12.428-5.493-12.428-12.428    C112.686,167.248,118.262,161.673,125.114,161.673z M301.386,212.629l-16.106,32.279c-0.051-0.036-4.866-3.457-18.46-13.112    c12.91-15.936,13.538-16.711,20.074-24.779L301.386,212.629z M255.98,242.498l9.989,7.093l-3.319,4.995h-13.34l-3.318-4.994    L255.98,242.498z M234.914,195.342v-8.463c6.87,2.463,14.291,3.576,21.169,3.576c7.307,0,14.639-1.472,20.923-3.928v8.863    l-21.026,25.955L234.914,195.342z M251.626,269.587h8.708l11.966,70.695H239.66L251.626,269.587z M322.357,114.661    c0,3.49-1.51,6.79-4.144,9.056c-1.298,1.116-2.799,1.934-4.439,2.435v-22.969C318.934,104.767,322.357,109.392,322.357,114.661z     M196.94,126.153c-1.64-0.501-3.142-1.318-4.438-2.433c-2.636-2.265-4.146-5.566-4.146-9.059c0-3.879,2.176-6.611,3.706-8.055    c0.025-0.022,0.051-0.041,0.076-0.064c1.389-1.288,3.046-2.27,4.802-2.928V126.153z M200.836,83.037    c-1.46,1.353-2.631,3.228-3.229,4.963c-1.031,0.155-2.054,0.367-3.065,0.632V75.818h-0.003c0-33.535,27.282-60.817,60.817-60.817    s60.817,27.283,60.817,60.817v12.465c-0.792-0.179-1.596-0.319-2.408-0.43c-0.077-2.66-0.711-4.268-3.204-7.297    c-2.315-2.808-6.487-7.105-16.066-17.4c-3.991-4.29-10.535-5.17-15.545-1.896c-20.47,13.372-45.593,20.246-68.95,18.573    C206.651,79.579,203.308,80.746,200.836,83.037z M211.941,132.766V95.357V94.97c14.112,0.62,28.559-1.432,42.282-5.698    c10.804-3.358,21.271-8.122,30.906-14.16c2.744,2.944,5.008,5.357,6.876,7.349c0.126,0.134,0.244,0.26,0.367,0.392    c0.67,0.714,1.311,1.398,1.908,2.036c2.048,2.188,3.629,3.896,4.491,4.901v42.976c0,23.569-19.226,42.689-42.69,42.689    C230.175,175.455,211.941,155.521,211.941,132.766z M225.036,207.028l20.08,24.786c-8.685,6.168-17.499,12.43-18.436,13.096    l-16.106-32.28L225.036,207.028z M131.541,270.619L131.541,270.619c0.001-25.92,21.849-35.769,23.243-36.37l41.737-16.181    l18.297,36.671v0.001c2.057,4.119,6.24,6.643,10.745,6.643c4.129,0,6.564-1.947,8.19-3.102l3.642,5.481l-12.952,76.52H179.08    v-58.72c0-4.142-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5c-4.142,0-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5v58.72h-32.538V270.619z M460.427,395.755    c0,0.875-0.711,1.586-1.586,1.586c-10.73,0-396.613,0-405.684,0c-0.875,0-1.586-0.712-1.586-1.586V356.87    c0-0.875,0.711-1.586,1.586-1.586c13.276,0,395.662,0,405.684,0c0.875,0,1.586,0.711,1.586,1.586V395.755z" data-original="#000000" class="active-path" data-old_color="#000000" fill="#B96969" data-llp-id="employee-0" data-llp-duration="2920" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style="" data-llp-stroke-join="" data-llp-stroke-cap=""/>
  </g>
</g></g> </svg>
```

I did everything according to the instructions, it seems that something went wrong, help me to solve this problem

Comment: There's presumably only one document so you need to put all your code in the one function.

Comment: I tried it, moved the function `#employee` to first function `#teamwork`, but it didnt work

Comment: Hard to say why unless you edit the question with that attempt

Comment: @Bieksa Please update your question with a working [mcve]. Use a stack snippet, jsfiddle, codepen etc.